# How do I install the Lego BOOST software on a phone instead of a tablet?

Tags: boost

Officially, the Lego Boost software is only available for devices with at least an 8 inch screen:

https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/device-guide/boost

However, it would be nice to install the software on an old phone rather than a tablet for my child to use. Is this possible? How?

Edit: LEGO now officially supports tablets and smartphones. This question is now mostly irrelevant, but it could still be useful as a guide to installing the app on an unsupported device.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can install the software using an alternative App Store such as APKPure. You can alternatively download and install the APK and OBB files directly from various online sources as demonstrated [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kUPBg-pvWA4). Once installed, this software seems to work for me on my Galaxy S4, and I assume it would also work on other Android devices. I can connect to and control the Move Hub without any issues, but I haven't tested all features of the software.

I was unable to get this to work on an S3. The app crashes during the loading screen. This could be due to many factors, but I suspect screen resolution could be one culprit, as the S3 has a 720p screen and the S4 has a 1080p screen.

It should also be noted that these devices aren't officially supported by TLG, so this software may be buggy and/or stop working in the future.

Devices confirmed working:

- ASUS ZenPad S
- Google Pixel C
- HTC Nexus 9
- Lenovo Yoga Tablet 2
- Lenovo Yoga Tab 3
- Nvidia SHIELD Tablet (LTE)
- Samsung Galaxy Tab S
- Samsung Galaxy Tab A
- Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 (Nook)
- Sony Xperia Z2 Tablet (LTE)
- Sony Xperia Z3 Tablet Compact (LTE)
- Xiaomi Mi Pad 2
- Samsung Galaxy S4
- LG G3
- Samsung Galaxy S5
- Google Pixel 2
- BQ Aquaris X5 Plus
- Huawei P10 Lite
- Motorola G5 Plus

Devices confirmed not working:

- Galaxy S3

Answer (score 0):

The official list of devices can be found here

https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/device-guide/boost